# How to use (phonegap, angularjs and jquery mobile) for windows phone 8?

Tags: jquery-mobile, angularjs, windows-phone-8, cordova

when I tried to run even a blank app, the console output is:
"Error calling js to fire nativeReady event. Did you include cordova.js in your html script tag?"

Doctype is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And this are script references:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/angular.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/angular-ui.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jqm-setup.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>-->
```

This error disappears only when I remove the jquery mobile stuff...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write now jquery mobile does not work for window-phone-8 application

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid JQuery Mobile in PhoneGap applications.  I got to meet Andrew Trice, Adobe PhoneGap Evangelist, at a DC Droid Meet and listened to him present in a few Webinars.  I've heard him say more than once that JQuery Mobile has huge performance issues.  He recommended using other frameworks if possible.  There are many other frameworks out there with good design, widgets, and samples that make them easy to learn.  I think he even created his own called AppUI.  Just look around and you'll find some really cool ones.

Answer (score 0):

That error is definitely what it says: your cordova.js file is not being included correctly.  Fix that first.

To answer your larger question: Angular, jQuery Mobile, and PhoneGap will play together but it comes with some big caveats.

The biggest issue is that the jQuery Angular Mobile adapter is currently abandoned while they invest time in building a better solution: angular-jqm.  That means that the adapter only works with outdated versions of the libraries.

Second: those outdated library versions have some issues working with Windows Phone.  These are fixable, too, but lock you into an even less maintainable version of them.

So here is the setup:

```
<script src="javascripts/vendor/jquery-mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
<!-- this angular-1.0.6 includes a patch to support WP8 URLs: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2303 -->
<script src="javascripts/vendor/angular-1.0.6.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/vendor/jquery-angular-mobile-adapter-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately I was never able to get partials to load via XHR so I included all pages in index.html document.

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">
  <div data-role="page" id="first" ng-controller="FirstController">
    <h1>First Page</h1>
    <p>{{foo}}</p>
    <p><a href="#/second">Second Page</a></p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="page" id="second" ng-controller="SecondController">
    <h2>Second Page</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Then you need to switch off a few niceties in the JavaScript and set up your routes:

```
<script>
var so_example = angular.module('so_example', []).
  config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $compileProvider) {
    // turn off html5 mode so that we just navigate around using hashes
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix("");
    // allow for the odd URLs included in Windows Mobile PhoneGap
    $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel|x-wmapp0):/);

    $routeProvider.
        when('/second', {
            templateUrl: '#second',
            jqmOptions: { transition: 'slide' } 
        }).
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: "#first"
        });
  }).
  controller("FirstController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.foo = "Hello, World!";
  }).
  controller("SecondController", function ($scope) {
  });
</script>
```

Now you need to leverage the Cordova library before you bootstrap Angular to your HTML:

```
var app = (function () {
  function onDeviceReady() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['so_example']);
    $.mobile.phonegapNavigationEnabled = true;
  }

  return {
    initialize: function() {
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    }
  };
})();
app.initialize();
```